# Query For Getting Value From two tables

Tags: ms-access

Hi i need your help on MS Access Database. I have two tables,tblExpense with three Columns(ExpenseID,ExpenseDate,Status) And tblExpenseDetails(ExpenseID,RefNo,Amount,Purpose).

Which Select Statement should i use if i want to get the Status from tblexpense using the RefNo from tblExpenseDetails?

Answer (score 0):

{`SELECT tblexpenseDetails.RefNo,tblexpense.Status,tblexpenses.ExpenseDate FROM tblExpense INNER JOIN tblexpenseDeatils ON tblexpensedetails.ExpenseID=tblexpenses.ExpenseID WHERE tblexpenseDetails.RefNo=?;`

Used That and it worked any other ideas are still welcome.

Comment: That won't work because the OP doesn't have fields `ExpenseDate` and `Status` in the `tblexpensedetails` table, or a `RefNo` field in the `tblexpenses` table, or a `ExpenseClaimRef` field in either table.